# Can I monitor all open apps on an android device with a Xamarin app?

Tags: c#, xamarin

Can I use a Xamarin app to monitor all of the apps open on an android device? I have searched around and found out how to *open* apps, but not how to view apps already opened. Also, is there an equivalent to the Windows System.Diagnostics Performance Counter class?

Comment: Like [discussed here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/83679/list-of-all-running-processes-in-android)?

Comment: @JNevill, that looks perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You can use following code to get the running app processes.

```
ActivityManager activityManager = GetSystemService(Context.ActivityService) as ActivityManager;
ActivityManager.MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
activityManager.GetMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);

List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcesses = activityManager.RunningAppProcesses as List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo>;
```

You can then loop through the list called `runningAppProcesses` and interrogate the process information class for other bits of information if required, these can be found listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.app.activitymanager.runningappprocessinfo?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9).

Here's a couple of examples:

- ProcessName- The name of the process that this object is associated with.
- Pid - The pid of this process; 0 if none.
- Uid - The user id of this process.

**2.** For information about `PerformanceCounter`,you can check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.performancecounter?view=netframework-4.8